# css for mobile device not working well

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am using bootstrap which I have converted into wordpress theme using [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/). 
Website url is [fuenterprises.com](http://www.fuenterprises.com)
My customized css for navbar is:

```
.navbar-wrapper {
  margin-top: 33px;
}

.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  margin: 0 0 0 100px;
  width: 91.3%;
}

.navbar-brand-logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.featurette-heading {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.featurette-heading a {
  color: inherit;
}

.img-responsive, .thumbnail > img, .thumbnail a > img, .carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed;
}
```

Now, When I open the site in mobile device, is not showing up menu as expected, see the screenshot:
[image: mobile screenshot]

Question is how can I disable image in mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a container

`<div class="disable-on-mobile"> <!-- my image --> </div>`

And add a CSS with a media query (depending on when you want to hide it change the width)

```
@media (max-width: 900px){

  .disable-on-mobile {
    display: none;
  }

}
```

You can also just add the class to your image...

Comment: thanks niels-van-renselaar, i changed the code as per your suggestion, @media (max-width: 767px){
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-brand-logo  {
    display: none;
  }
}
but now my logo is overlapping the navbar

Comment: one more thing, the menu is not opening now when it is switched to mobile view

Comment: ok I have done it. i was missing the id of the div container for menu. i.e. id="navbar"